# Differentiate: $y=e^{ax^3}$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$y=e^{ax^3}$

What in a problem indicates I should use the laws of logarithm?

Here is how I differentiated the function:

$\ln(y)=\ln{e^{ax^3}}$

$\ln(y)=ax^3\ln(e)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}=3ax^2\cdot (1)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}\cdot\frac{1}{y}\cdot (y)=\ (y)\ 3ax^2\cdot (1)$

$\frac{dy}{dx}=\ e^{ax^3}\ 3ax^2$

Comment: what's your question?

Comment: the result of your derivative is ok

Comment: What in a problem indicates I should use the laws of logarithm? for example: $y=e^{-2t} cos\ 4t$ Should I use the laws of logarithm?

Comment: For the question in the comment: first product rule,  then chain rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this, but I would just use the chain rule:

$(e^{ax^3})' = e^{ax^3} (ax^3)' = e^{ax^3} 3ax^2$.

More generally $(e^{f(x)})' = e^{f(x)} f'(x)$ for any differentiable function $f(x)$.

To differentiate $e^{-2t} \cos (4t)$, one can first use the product rule:
$$(e^{-2t} \cos (4t)) = (e^{-2t})' \cos (4t) + e^{-2t} \ (\cos (4t))'$$
then use the chain rule for $(e^{-2t})'$ and $(\cos (4t))'$.

Comment: Can the same be done for this question?  $y=e^{-2t} cos\ 4t$

Answer (score 2):

$$y=e^{ax^3}$$
$$\ln y= \ln(e^{ax^3})$$
$$\ln y= ax^3$$
$$\frac 1y\frac{dy}{dx}=3ax^2$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3ax^2\cdot y$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=3ax^2 e^{ax^3}$$

So your work is correct. Of course, this would be more easily done with the chain rule.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculus is correct. You can find the same result also using the chain rule:
$$
\dfrac{d}{dx}e^{ax^3}= e^{ax^3}\dfrac{d}{dx}(ax^3)=3ax^2e^{ax^3}
$$

Answer (score 0):

> Hint:computational

$y=e^{f(x)}$then $\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{f(x)}f^1(x)$

$y=e^{ax^3}$

$=>\frac{dy}{dx}=e^{ax^3}\frac{d}{dx}(ax^3)=e^{ax^3}(3ax^2)$